# Unable to Build 3.1.3 Device on iPhone SDK 4?

Tags: ios4

I just installed iPhone SDK 4, and i couldnt build app on 3.1.3 devices?

it says the SDK 3.1.3 is missing, did apple remove the previous SDK?

How do we test on the previous iPhone OS version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 3.1.3 was removed. Make sure you read release notes before installing beta software ;)

Answer (score 0):

3.1.3 is deprecated for building, not as a target. More info in my community wiki on this, here:

[Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385)